# Remove highlighting of the clicked part in flot

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot, clickable

I'll take as an example this plot: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/interacting/

As you can see, if you click a point it will remain highlighted. Not an issue with static graphs, but I have a graph that is updated every second.

How could I make this highlighted part disappear after a certain period, e.g. 5 seconds?

This is the flot code for the above chart (clickable elements):

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
        if (item) {
            $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
            plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the highlight after 5 seconds, you can use a timer for the `unhighlight()` function:

```
$("#placeholder").bind("plotclick", function (event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
        $("#clickdata").text(" - click point " + item.dataIndex + " in " + item.series.label);
        plot.highlight(item.series, item.datapoint);

        setTimeout(function() {
            plot.unhighlight(item.series, item.datapoint);
        }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I've already done that (my current solution is to unhighlight the previous element after clicking on next one), but what I'm really interested in (and have no clue) is how to do this time-wise (e.g. put some "time sleep" in-between) ..

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks!